# Why I get NULL is undefined error?

Tags: c

I have this thiis row:

```
while (**arr != NULL)
```

In this row I get this error:

```
identifier "NULL" is undefined
```

I included this library:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

but still I get the error above.Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Try including `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: `NULL` is supposed to be defined in <stdio.h> as per standard, no? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL

Comment: It is defined in `stddef.h` per standard. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19

Comment: By the way, the expression `**arr` is suspect, it makes you look like a three star programmer, which is [seldom a good thing](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) to be called.

Comment: Do you check `*arr!=NULL` before checking `**arr!=NULL`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. And in `<stdio.h>` as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah.. which is a bit strange

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added #include<stdlib.h>

Comment: Then you will have to give us [mcve].

Comment: Can you please specify what compiler/IDE/OS are you using? As well as providing an [MCVE].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` are, in fact, required to define `NULL`, [all the way back to the original ANSI C standard in 1989](https://web.archive.org/web/20151125170555/http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt)<sup>1</sup> (unfortunately this is a .txt file, so I can't link to a specific section; search for `4.9 INPUT/OUTPUT <stdio.h>` and/or `4.10 GENERAL UTILITIES <stdlib.h>`, and then scroll down a little).  If either of the minimized test programs

```
#include <stdio.h>
void *p = NULL;
```

or

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *p = NULL;
```

fails to compile to an object file, then your C implementation is buggy.  (If  the above test programs do *not* fail to compile, you're gonna need to do some [delta-minimization](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/527) on your actual program, and probably then track down your wiseacre cow-orker who thought it would be funny to put `#undef NULL` in an application header file.)

NULL is also required to be defined in several other standard headers, but its *true* home, as you may guess from the cross-references to section 4.1.5 to explain what NULL is supposed to be defined *to*, is `stddef.h`.  A C implementation that fails to define `NULL` in `stddef.h` is *egregiously* buggy.  Also, `stddef.h` is one of the very few headers that is required to be provided by a "freestanding implementation"; if you are working in an embedded environment, it's possible that they thought they could get away with leaving NULL out of `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h`, but they have no excuse whatsoever for leaving it out of `stddef.h`.

In the alternative, just use `0` for the null pointer constant.  That's perfectly fine style as long as all your functions have prototypes.  (You have to cast it to pass it correctly to a function that takes a variable number of arguments, e.g. to `execl`, but you have to cast *NULL* to pass it correctly to a function that takes a variable number of arguments, so it comes out in the wash.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Footnote for historians: yes, the linked document really is the *ANSI* C standard, not the ISO standard with nigh-identical wording (but very different section numbering) that came out a year later.  I am not aware of any copy of the 1990 edition of the ISO C standard that is available online at no charge.

Comment: I added all this:

#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>

And still I get the error.

I use visualstudio2017

Comment: @Michael Do you still get the error with the minimal test programs I showed?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 should be at least adequately compliant with the C standard.  You probably have a broken installation.  I would suggest uninstalling it, manually searching for and erasing all vestiges of the installation, and then re-downloading and re-installing from scratch.  If that doesn't fix it you're going to have to take it up with Microsoft tech support.  I can't help you any further, I don't use VS myself.